# Library or jar that displays the remote system process list in Java

Tags: java, monitoring

I am searching a library or jar file for making a system monitoring program. I found that Java provides jConsole, but I need some other jar file name.
actually i am making a  web service in which i have ip address and port no of remote computer and based on that i need a system process list of that computer, and that web service i will call from the google apps engine that will display the whole process list. so i need name of jar file that can i place on server and that give me the process list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built such a system before and JMX (java management extensions) was very useful.

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html

examples and tutorials:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/

You can install small agents on the machines you wish to monitor. These will gather information and either push it to a main monitoring server or the monitoring server will pull data whenever it wants from those monitored clients.

You will also need to have a database to store which attributes on which machines nodes you are monitoring. You can serialize the attributes with [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), which creates an xml out of java objects and vice versa. You can store these in the database.

The attributes can be monitored by creating beans on the monitored machines.

You might also want to give [Nagios](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/toc.html) a try - a commercial solution.

There is no jar file that you can get for free and just add it to your project (at least none that I know of right now).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what you are looking for, given that you din't provide much information. It sounds like you might be interested in [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html).